# I have to get a message if textbox has null value for double value

Tags: c#

I have to get a message if a textbox has null value for double value, i tried the below code, but got an error on the 2nd condition, please help!

```
acno = Txtacc.Text;
recoverymoney = double.Parse(Txtamount.Text);

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Txtacc.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have not entered account number, Please Enter it...!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Txtamount.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have not entered amount, Please Enter it..!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: What error?....

Comment: What is "a error 2nd condition"?  What's the actual problem?

Comment: Read and use double.TryParse instead.

Comment: You will get an error here: `recoverymoney = double.Parse(Txtamount.Text);` if your value cannot be parsed to `double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Txtacc.Text)) {
  MessageBox.Show("You have not entered account number, Please Enter it...!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
} else if (!myDbContect.Accounts.Any(a => a.AccountNumber == this.Txtacc.Text)) {
  MessageBox.Show("You have not entered a valid account number, Please Enter it...!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
} else if (!double.TryParse(Txtamount.Text, out double myrecoverymoney)) {
  MessageBox.Show("The amount value you entered is not parseable to a double.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
// do something with account and myrecoverymoney
```

And prefer to use a decimal for money, amount and alike instead of a double.

Comment: @Cetin Basoz: see erro: A local or parameter named 'recoverymoney' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Comment: @RoshanAbrew, isn't that obvious? Do not use that in an enclosing scope or use a different name. I am editing for you.

Comment: @RoshanAbrew, BTW I didn't notice before you were saying account number, maybe you don't want to parse an account number to a double but it would be the amount. It is also interesting, you allow end user to enter an account number to a textbook and you only check for it not being null or empty. In a good interface, you should be checking the account number's existence on the db.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: account number is ok, but not work amount

Comment: @RoshanAbrew, I don't know how that is OK if you don't control it. Anyway I edited for you with control of account number.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: Thanks a lot now it is working properly

Answer (score 2):

You should do this using `double.TryParse`, and you should actually read the values after your checks:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Txtacc.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have not entered account number, Please Enter it...!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Txtamount.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have not entered amount, Please Enter it..!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
eise if(!double.TryParse(this.Txtamount.Text, out recoverymoney ))
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have entered an invalid amount, Please Enter a number..!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
acno = Txtacc.Text
```

Comment: got error: A local or parameter named 'recoverymoney' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Comment: @RoshanAbrew remove `var` keyword then.

Comment: @RoshanAbrew Where? `double.TryParse` will not throw such error.

Comment: @RoshanAbrew you must still have the `double.Parse` line in `TryParse` doesnt throw that exception

Comment: @Jamiec: after got error:  input string was not in a correct format

Comment: @Jamiec: I used (double.Parse) after gor error for recoverymoney